# Check if two 3D points visibility is blocked by a 3D shape

Tags: java, geometry

I'm looking for better options on a method that returns if two 3D points can "see" each other behind a 3D "wall"/flat shape.

What I already use for wall shapes (point1XY, point2XY and mixZ maxZ) that works pretty well.

```
for (ShapeHolder shape : allShapes)
{
    final int denominator = ((ty - y) * (shape.getPoint1X() - shape.getPoint2X())) - ((tx - x) * (shape.getPoint1Y() - shape.getPoint2Y()));
    if (denominator == 0)
    {
        continue;
    }

    final float multiplier1 = (float) (((shape.getPoint2X() - shape.getPoint1X()) * (y - shape.getPoint1Y())) - ((shape.getPoint2Y() - shape.getPoint1Y()) * (x - shape.getPoint1X()))) / denominator;
    final float multiplier2 = (float) (((tx - x) * (y - shape.getPoint1Y())) - ((ty - y) * (x - shape.getPoint1X()))) / denominator;
    if ((multiplier1 >= 0) && (multiplier1 <= 1) && (multiplier2 >= 0) && (multiplier2 <= 1))
    {
        final int intersectZ = Math.round(z + (multiplier1 * (tz - z)));
        if ((intersectZ > shape.getZMin()) && (intersectZ < shape.getZMax()))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

My main problem is how I can use this code for abstract 4 sided shapes, with different Z values.
Like input the coordinates of a 4-sided flat 3D polygon and the coordinates of two points to return the boolean value of whenever the two points visibility is blocked by the shape.

Something like:

```
public boolean checkIfObjectBetween(int aX, int aY, int aZ, int bX, int bY, int bZ, int p1X, int p1Y, int p1Z, int p2X, int p2Y, int p2Z, int p3X, int p3Y, int p3Z, int p4X, int p4Y, int p4Z)
{
    if (A can see B)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[image: graphic explanation]

Comment: This is not a coding service. Show what you tried.

Comment: I did not add what I tried, because I don't think it would be helpful.

Comment: @user1803551 The wording *"I need a method..."* suggests that SO is abused as a coding service, but one could simply imagine a different wording here (like "I'm looking for options / approaches..."), making it perfectly reasonable (and, particularly, helpful for people who are searching for similar tasks - posting hundreds of lines of failed attempts is not necessarily helpful here). (But this refers to this particular question - I perfectly agree with your general statement, the decline in question quality and the abuse of SO as a homework-making-machine)

Comment: Well, downvotes are OK - e.g. if someone thinks that the question does not show enough research effort. But voting to close this as "too broad" is just ridiculous. It's a clear (maybe rather "to narrow") question, with a clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this basically consists of

- Creating a line segment between the points
- Dividing the plane (rectangle) into two triangles
- Checking the line segment for intersections with each of the triangles

For the line segment-triangle intersection test, an adaption of the [Möller–Trumbore intersection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ller%E2%80%93Trumbore_intersection_algorithm) can be used. In its original form, this only refers to **rays**. In order to use it for **line segments**, one additionally has to check whether both points of the line segment are on different sides of the triangle.

Below is a **very** simple and straightforward solution for that. (It also contains an implementation of the Möller–Trumbore test, but this is not used - only included for reference). The `planeIsBetweenPoints` method does the intersection tests by calling `lineSegmentTriangleIntersection` for both triangles.

Note that this is a *really* simplistic implementation, and I avoided any external dependencies to make it a standalone example. In a larger context, one could expect to have classes like a `Vector3D` for basic vector operations, which in the example below are emulated with `double[3]` arrays and appropriate helper functions.

```
public class PlaneIsBetweePoints
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(planeIsBetweenPoints(
            5,5,-5, 
            5,5, 5, 
            0,10,0, 
            10,10,0, 
            10,0,0, 
            0,0,0));
        System.out.println(planeIsBetweenPoints(
            5,5, 5, 
            5,5,-5, 
            0,10,0, 
            10,10,0, 
            10,0,0, 
            0,0,0));
        System.out.println(planeIsBetweenPoints(
            5,5, 5, 
            5,5,10, 
            0,10,0, 
            10,10,0, 
            10,0,0, 
            0,0,0));
        System.out.println(planeIsBetweenPoints(
            5,5,-10, 
            5,5,-5, 
            0,10,0, 
            10,10,0, 
            10,0,0, 
            0,0,0));
    }


    public static boolean planeIsBetweenPoints(
        int p0x, int p0y, int p0z, 
        int p1x, int p1y, int p1z, 
        int v0x, int v0y, int v0z, 
        int v1x, int v1y, int v1z, 
        int v2x, int v2y, int v2z, 
        int v3x, int v3y, int v3z)
    {
        double p0[] = { p0x, p0y, p0z };
        double p1[] = { p1x, p1y, p1z };
        double v0[] = { v0x, v0y, v0z };
        double v1[] = { v1x, v1y, v1z };
        double v2[] = { v2x, v2y, v2z };
        double v3[] = { v3x, v3y, v3z };

        return 
            lineSegmentTriangleIntersection(p0, p1, v0, v1, v2) ||
            lineSegmentTriangleIntersection(p0, p1, v0, v2, v3);
    }

    private static final double EPSILON = 0.000001;
    private static void CROSS(double result[], double v0[], double v1[])
    {
        result[0] = v0[1] * v1[2] - v0[2] * v1[1];
        result[1] = v0[2] * v1[0] - v0[0] * v1[2];
        result[2] = v0[0] * v1[1] - v0[1] * v1[0];
    }

    private static double DOT(double v0[], double v1[])
    {
        return v0[0] * v1[0] + v0[1] * v1[1] + v0[2] * v1[2]; 
    }

    private static void SUB(double result[], double v0[], double v1[])
    {
        result[0] = v0[0] - v1[0];
        result[1] = v0[1] - v1[1];
        result[2] = v0[2] - v1[2];
    }

    private static void SCALE(double result[], double v[], double f)
    {
        result[0] = v[0] * f;
        result[1] = v[1] * f;
        result[2] = v[2] * f;
    }

    // Adapted Möller-Trumbore test for line segments
    public static boolean lineSegmentTriangleIntersection(
        double p0[], double p1[],
        double v0[], double v1[], double v2[]) 
    {
        double edge1[] = new double[3];
        double edge2[] = new double[3];
        double tVec[] = new double[3];
        double pVec[] = new double[3];
        double qVec[] = new double[3];
        double dir[] = new double[3];
        double normal[] = new double[3];

        SUB(edge1, v1, v0);
        SUB(edge2, v2, v0);
        SUB(dir, p1, p0);
        SCALE(dir, dir, 1.0 / Math.sqrt(DOT(dir, dir)));
        CROSS(pVec, dir, edge2);
        double det = DOT(edge1, pVec);
        if (det > -EPSILON && det < EPSILON)
        {
            return false;
        }
        double invDet = 1.0 / det;
        SUB(tVec, p0, v0);
        double u = DOT(tVec, pVec) * invDet;
        if (u < 0.0 || u > 1.0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        CROSS(qVec, tVec, edge1);
        double v = DOT(dir, qVec) * invDet;
        if (v < 0.0 || (u + v) > 1.0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        CROSS(normal, edge1, edge2);
        SCALE(normal, normal, 1.0 / Math.sqrt(DOT(normal, normal)));
        double d0 = DOT(normal, p0);
        double d1 = DOT(normal, p1);
        return (d0 > 0) != (d1 > 0);
    }


    //=========================================================================
    // The part below is an overly simple implementation of  
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/
    //     M%C3%B6ller%E2%80%93Trumbore_intersection_algorithm
    // only as a reference

    public static boolean rayTriangleIntersection(
        double origin[], double dir[],
        double v0[], double v1[], double v2[],
        double tuv[]) 
    {
        double edge1[] = new double[3];
        double edge2[] = new double[3];
        double tVec[] = new double[3];
        double pVec[] = new double[3];
        double qVec[] = new double[3];

        SUB(edge1, v1, v0);
        SUB(edge2, v2, v0);
        CROSS(pVec, dir, edge2);
        double det = DOT(edge1, pVec);
        if (det > -EPSILON && det < EPSILON)
        {
            return false;
        }
        double invDet = 1.0 / det;
        SUB(tVec, origin, v0);
        double u = DOT(tVec, pVec) * invDet;
        if (u < 0.0 || u > 1.0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        CROSS(qVec, tVec, edge1);
        double v = DOT(dir, qVec) * invDet;
        if (v < 0.0 || (u + v) > 1.0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        double t = DOT(edge2, qVec) * invDet;
        if (t > EPSILON)
        {
            tuv[0] = t;
            tuv[1] = u;
            tuv[2] = v;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.